# GAE PHP runs localhost, but results in 404 in all files after pushed using push-to-deploy

Tags: git, google-app-engine, deployment

I had a running version of my app today running...

```
application: myapp3
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true 

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|php))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|php))

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /home
  script: home.php

- url: /contact
  script: contact.php

- url: /gallery
  script: gallery.php

- url: /reservation
  script: reservation.php

- url: /contact
  script: contact.php

- url: /location
  script: location.php

- url: /
  script: index.php
```

Everything works in localhost

- All php files are in the same root directory
- the js and css directory exists.
- URLs without the ".php" extension are given for individual php files.

Not sure what's wrong... All the push-to-deploy executions work, as I can verify the latest commit in the UI...

```
(master) $ git push appengine master
Counting objects: 10, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 717 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Scanning pack: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Storing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Processing commits: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Deploying...
remote: Created deployment: myapp3.clouddev.gaeTemplate-d981b975f1ecaa6d.deployment_XXXXXXX
remote: Dispatched
remote: Deployment 'myapp3@clouddev@gaeTemplate-d981b975f1ecaa6d@deployment_XXXXXXXXX' is in PENDING.
remote: Scanning files on local disk.
remote: Initiating update.
remote: Scanned 500 files.
remote: Cloning 571 static files.
remote: Scanned 250 files.
remote: Cloning 24 application files.
remote: Sending batch containing 1 file(s) totaling 1KB.
remote: Uploading 1 files.
remote: Uploaded 1 files.
remote: Deploying new version.
remote: Updated successfully
remote: Closing update: new version is ready to start serving.
remote: Deployment 'myapp3@clouddev@gaeTemplate-YYYYYYYY@deployment_1385330578455@XXXXXXXXXXXXXX' is in RUNNING.

remote: Deployment to AppEngine successful.
To https://code.google.com/id/XXXXXXXXX/
   d29ee70..fc90c93  master -> master
```